# Greatest term of this expansion?

Tags: binomial-theorem

If in the expansion of $(x+a)^{15}$ the $11^{\text{th}}$ term is G. M. i.e. geometric mean of $8^{\text{th}}$ and $12^{\text{th}}$ terms then which term is the greatest term among the terms in expansion of $(x+a)^{15}$?

Comment: You should format your question better. As it stands, no one knows what you meant to write.

Comment: Not sure this can help. But have a look to this page: http://www.math-for-all-grades.com/Numericallygreatestterm.html

Comment: I have edited the question please try it!

Comment: Do you start counting from $0$ or $1$?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Derive that $x$ is a multiple of $ a$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the binomial theorem we have
\begin{align*}
(x+a)^{15}=\sum_{j=0}^{15}\binom{15}{j}x^ja^{15-j}
\end{align*}

Since the $11^{\text{th}}$ term is the geometric mean of the the $8^{\text{th}}$ and $12^{\text{th}}$ term, we have
\begin{align*}
\binom{15}{10}x^{10}a^5&=\sqrt{\binom{15}{7}x^7a^8\binom{15}{11}x^{11}a^4}\\
&=x^9a^6\sqrt{\binom{15}{7}\binom{15}{11}}\\
\end{align*}

> Simplification with $a\ne 0$ gives
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{x}{a}&=\frac{\sqrt{\binom{15}{7}\binom{15}{11}}}{\binom{15}{10}}=\ldots=\frac{5}{77}\sqrt{231}\approx0.98\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In order to find the greatest term we compare successive terms we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\binom{15}{j+1}x^{j+1}a^{14-j}&>\binom{15}{j}x^ja^{15-j}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
Simplification of (2) gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{a}&>\binom{15}{j}\binom{15}{j+1}^{-1}=\ldots=\frac{j+1}{15-j}\\
\end{align*}

> After rearrangement we get $j$ on the left-hand side and evaluation according (1) gives 
>   \begin{align*}
> j&<\frac{15\frac{x}{a}-1}{\frac{x}{a}+1}\bigg|_{\frac{x}{a}=\frac{5}{77}\sqrt{231}}\approx 6.8\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude $j=6$ and the greatest term is according to (2) the term at the left-hand side of (2) which is (with $j+1=7$) the $8^{\text{th}}$ term
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\binom{15}{7}x^7a^8}
> \end{align*}